Ubuntu GNOME desktop freezing randomly
I'm running Ubuntu with GNOME with following software and hardware configurations:
$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

BIOS
American Megatrends Inc.
BIOS version
6203
BIOS date
July 27, 2023
CPU
16x AMD Ryzen 7 1800X Eight-Core Processor

$sudo dmidecode -t 2 
# dmidecode 3.5
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3.0 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: PRIME X370-PRO
    Version: Rev X.0x
    Serial Number: 810566617029619
    Asset Tag: Default string
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Default string
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0


Graphics card:
NVIDIA
GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
$gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 46.0

About my problem:
The GNOME desktop freezes randomly which also renders mouse and keyboard inoerative, so I cannot ssh into the box or use CTRL+ALT+F3 (or any other terminal) and my only choice is to hard reset for a system reboot. I've  ran fsck on the disk and also ran memtest86+ v7.0 (for 18+ hours for 12 passes) and found no errors in either tests.
I recently installed Cockpit to troubleshoot this problem and the last time I had to reset the machines was at 4:29PM and here are the logs that I see in cockpit around that time frame. Please let me know if you see anything abnormal or possible root cause of this desktop freezing:
Reboot log
Thanks.

Have you checked the AsusTek support website for possible BIOS/Complementary metal Oxide firmware updates?

Do you have swap space? free  will tell you. In general, 1.5 x RAM is a good choice for swap size. Read man free mkswap swapon fstab.

Yes, I've swap available and not sure if this is enough. Here are more details:                     $free                total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available Mem:        32765564     2486796    28327876       51436     2438908    30278768 Swap:        2097148           0     2097148

@nwdolphin0227
Yes, I've uipdated BIOS from ASUS a few times and found one more update that was applied so the firrmware seems current as of now. Thanks for your pointer.

A day or two later, I found few error logs related to GNS3 which I do not need currently. So I uninstalled GNS3 and all related dependencies including VM completely, removed the entries from apt.sources and ran "apt autopurge".
The GNOME seems stable since then and it has been ~10 days and it has not frozen even once on me. Just in case it helps anyone, monitoring logs did help and seems like a good practice for me going forward.
